# Create jar in directory other than target with maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-assembly-plugin

My java project structure is as follows

```
├── code
│   ├── java
│   │   └── PROJECT
│   │       ├── pom.xml
│   │       └── src
```

After deployment the directory structure is coming as

```
../PROJECT/target/xyz.jar
```

Now if I want to create the jar file as without "target" directory, how to achieve it. Example

```
../PROJECT/xyz.jar
```

My Maven assembly file used is

```
   <fileSet>
        <directory>code/java/</directory>
        <outputDirectory>jlib/</outputDirectory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
```

Can some one please help to achieve the above ?

Comment: Change the output directory in the `configuration` of the `maven-assembly-plugin` in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Changing the standard directories for Maven should only be done if absolutely necessary. Furthermore, writing outside of `target` should be avoided. Are you really sure you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us a little bit more information about your build and deployment process?

- Is there a reason why you don't want it in the target directory (e.g. you build on your target server)?

You taged also `jenkins`. You could do a simple move statement as shell after building your application to move your jar file(s) into an other directory:

```
mv jlib/PROJECT/target/xyz.jar jlib/PROJECT/xyz.jar
```

Comment: This is not really an answer, but a comment. If you do not have enough reputation to write a comment, please don't write an answer instead.

Comment: In my opinion my second point is a answer. It is maybe not the perfekt way to do it, but it should work. Because of that I had the question at the beginning. If there will be an answer I can deliver maybe a better answer.